# Precision Recall scores doesn't match visualization

Tags: python, matplotlib, auc, precision-recall

I am calculating the Precision Recall score for 3 different models.
For my first model, the plot does not match the auc score which is 0.85 but it should be 0.5.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_test, pred1)
print(pred1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(recall, precision, color='red')

ax.set_title('Precision-Recall curve')
ax.set_ylabel('Precision')
ax.set_xlabel('Recall')
plt.show()

auc_precision_recall = auc(recall, precision)
```

Comment: `ax.plot()` will just plot the values you give it.. if the line is not as expected then you should perhaps check the `precision` and `recall` values returned by `precision_recall_curve()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I don't have enough rep to comment.

Notice your y-axis, it is between 0.7-1, so an AUC of 0.85 seems to match the plot. The AUC would be 0.5 if the y-axis ranges from 0-1.

You can set the y-axis to be between 0-1 with `ax.set_ylim((0,1))`

Comment: thanks somehow I didn't notice that